# What will be voltage drop across 1N4007 Bridge wave rectifier at 24 volts AC?

Tags: diodes

Actually... I'm finding the response of 1N4007 Bridge Wave Rectifier at INPUT Voltage 24 Volts AC with 2 Ampere Current taken from a Step down Transformer which provides us output of 24 volts AC. So please show me that what will be voltage drop across 1N4007 Bridge Wave Rectifier at 24 volts AC?

Comment: your question is unclear **1)** 1N4007 is not rated for 2 A **2)** The voltage drop is not related to the **voltage** but the **current** so mentioning it is 24 V AC is useless. Also many questions about transformers and bridge rectifiers have been asked on this site already. Look them up and learn from them. Then come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: Compute max Discharge current/(duty cycle)= max charge current then lookup VI curve for Vf*2 to get bridge drop. On a good design of diode selection 1.4~1.6Vmax per pair. Typicall Vdc is 1.5x RMS with +141% for rms to pk and +10% for transformer load loss and -1.4V for bridge drop. For 10% ripple at max load current. RC=>=8T for T=1/2f

Comment: @FakeMoustache 1A diodes make a 2A bridge, very roughly speaking, because only one pair conducts at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If the bridge rectifier arrangement uses 1N4007 devices (and a large output capacitor to filter some of the voltage ripply and supply current for part of each half-cycle) and this is the usual situation where you expect to use an average draw of \$2\:\textrm{A}\$, then the diodes will be experiencing much higher peak currents than \$2\:\textrm{A}\$. In such situations, peak currents may reach roughly 5 times that much and you might easily see \$1.2\:\textrm{V}\$ across a single diode.

But you probably can't use the 1N4007 anyway. Peak currents are, I think, too high. Just to pick something with an equivalent reverse voltage and a safer average current spec (and not because I'm recommending it) you might look at devices like Rohm's [RFN5TF8S](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/diode/fast_recovery/rfn5tf8s.pdf).

Either way, the boilerplate \$0.7\:\textrm{V}\$ estimate is always wrong in cases such as the one you outlined. You will never see it. (And I've never seen a Schottky that could even get up close to that kind of reverse voltage spec.)

Comment: 1N4007 is rated for AVERAGE currents, and in a bridge rectifier only has 50% duty cycle.   It's not impossible to do 2A DC output, just marginal.   Peak rating is huge (over 10A).

Comment: @Whit3rd I'm just reading the OP (not that I fully understand that.) I interpreted "2 Ampere Current taken" as a mean. Mostly, I was focused answering "what will be voltage drop across..." and don't intend on getting caught up in a debate about whether or not a 1N4007 is okay. (It is, or it isn't.) The point is about the voltage drop. The rest I could have just edited out, I suppose, and I wouldn't have minded.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb for a single silicon diode's forward drop is about 0.7 volts, so since there are always two diodes in series in a full-wave bridge, the drop across the bridge will be about 1.4 volts.

Comment: OK for the two diodes that are *conducting*, but what about the two diodes in the *reverse* direction?

Comment: The other 2 diodes are not conducting so they don't have any voltage drop.  The voltage across them will vary during the cycle up to the peak voltage coming from the input (minus diode drops which you can ignore for that reverse rating).

Comment: That will never happen in a bridge outlined on the OP. The drop will be significantly higher. I can't see how you got there.